# Exporting single objects at a time to an array of objects in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, export

I am using node.js & I have a loop that results in returning a single object as follows:

```
Output {
  prop1:"val1",
  prop2:"val2",
  ..
}
```

The object is returned every 10 sec and it can hold different keys every time besides the different values.

I know I can write the object to a JSON file using the `fs` module just as follows:

```
var jsonOutput = JSON.stringify(Output);
fs.writeFile("output.json", jsonOutput, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("An error occured while writing JSON Object to File.");
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("JSON file has been saved.");
});
```

This results in a JSON file of a single object.
Now how can I export the object to the same json file where it is accumulated with all the other previous exports (like an array of objects) **wihtout** the need to store it as an array of objects in the first place?

Comment: Perhaps remove the top and bottom line and adding those to the string when you read the file for processing? Then you can just append to the file. Alternatively write a CSV

Comment: Why would you Not want to store it as an array to begin with? If not having to parse the entire array every time matters, you probably want a database anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the follwoing:

1. Stringify the JSON and prettify by doing `JSON.stringify(Output, null, 4/*or 2*/)`;
2. Remove the last line and write the entire json to file.
3. Next time, after step 1 remove the first and last line, and then add a `comma(,)` and append the string to the file.
   and so on and so forth.

When you are reading the file, add a `}` after the file content then `JSON.parse` it. Or whenever you are exiting the program you can do that also.